# "Proof" check on Qn. 6 1988 IMO

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Inspired by a video I watched on Qn 6, I decided to give it a try. Now I have never heard of this question nor have I read up on the proof and am a complete amateur in mathematics in general. The problem is that I have come up with what looks like a proof but I'm sure there is a flaw or some loose end somewhere I just don't know where.

Given to positive integers $a,b$ such that $ab + 1$ perfectly divides the sum of their squares. Show that $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}$$ is equal to a perfect square number.

Now to start off, I have the cosine rule

$$a^2 + b^2 -2abcos\theta = c^2$$
Where theta is the angle opposite the side c of some triangle with lengths a,b,c.

Now suppose $$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}=n^2$$ then $$c^2 +2abcos\theta=n^2 + abn^2$$

Now we can consider two situations. If we let $c^2=n^2$ then it implies that $$n^2=2abcos\theta$$ then $n^2=1$ is the only solution. However then
$$\frac{a^2 + b^2}{ab+1}=1$$
$$a^2+b^2=ab+1$$
$$(a-b)^2=1-ab$$
Which is possible only when a and/or b equals zero.

Now consider the second possibility, that $n^2=2abcos\theta$. Now it is always possible to divide the product $ab$ by some factor $s$ such that it equals a square number. We can easily define a theta such that

$$cos\theta=\frac{1}{2s}$$.

Since $s$ is an integer and greater or equal to 1, such a \theta always exists. Which means that one can always construct a triangle with side lengths a and b that satisfies initial conditions such that $$c^2-2abcos\theta=n^{2}(ab+1) $$ for some integer n, which completes the proof.

Comment: You bring in $c$; it's unclear what this is. A bit later you write $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}=n^2$; so you prove that $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a square by **assuming** it's a square?

Comment: No c is just there to complete the equation I learned in school and there's a typo. It's $c^2=n^2$.  Yes I assume that it is square and show that this is always possible. I think at least that's what I did.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown By assuming that it is square and that there is no contradiction surely it can be considered correct. There's no need for a proof by contradiction is there?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is correct.

From
$c^2 +2ab\cos\theta=n^2 + abn^2
$
you consider only
two possibilities:
$n^2=c$
or
$n^2 = 2ab\cos\theta$.

However,
$n^2$
could be some other value
that makes the equality hold;
nothing there
prevents this.

Comment: Sorry there's a typo it's $c^2=n^2$

Comment: True but I think that these two possibilities already show that there exists an n which solves the Qn. If there is another value which can solve it it doesn't matter since there is already a value which solves the equation?

Comment: So my "proof" is incomplete? Is it possible to complete my proof or is this method just the wrong way to do it. Unfortunately I don't have the know how to fix this, if it can even be fixed.